# limit, choice the UNION duplicate checking columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, union

I have two tables like the following :

**parameters1**

```
+------+-----+
| cod  | des |
+------+-----+
|  1   | aaa |
|  2   | bbb |
|  3   | ccc |
```

**parameters2**

```
+------+-----+
| cod  | des |
+------+-----+
|  1   | mmm |
```

I usually JOIN the result set of this two tables with an UNION in this way :

```
SELECT  cod,  des 
FROM parameters1
UNION 
SELECT  cod,  des 
FROM parameters2
```

and i get this result set :

```
+------+-----+
| cod  | des |
+------+-----+
|  1   | aaa |
|  2   | bbb |
|  3   | ccc |
|  1   | mmm |
```

*I want to limit the UNION duplicate checking only to the `cod` column, so i want to avoid that the 1 cod get duplicated in the result set (when there is a record with different name and the same cod), i want to get the name from the first table (**parameters1**)* :

```
+------+-----+
| cod  | des |
+------+-----+
|  1   | aaa |
|  2   | bbb |
|  3   | ccc |
```

**UPDATE** 
If i remove the record `1` from the **parameters1** table(`DELETE FROM parameters1 WHERE cod = 1`) i should get this result set :

```
+------+-----+
| cod  | des |
+------+-----+
|  1   | mmm |   ---> FROM parameters2
|  2   | bbb |
|  3   | ccc |
```

Is it possible to limit the duplicate checking of a UNION to only one field or some fields ? How ?

The solution should work on a multidatabase environment (MSSQL, PostgreSQL, MySQL).

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Distinct Union for one column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338884/sql-server-distinct-union-for-one-column)

Comment: Please explain the logic of why the row `(1, 'aaa')` is chosen over the row `(1, 'mmm')` e.g. because `'aaa' < 'mmm'`, perhaps? The accepted answer seems to pick an arbitrary row.

Comment: It is logic that i have defined because one table have precedence ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT  cod, des 
FROM parameters1 p1
UNION ALL
SELECT  cod, des 
FROM parameters2 p2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM parameters1 p1sub
    WHERE p1sub.cod = p2.cod
)
```

Comment: @ypercube Very good point, don't need to try to filter out any duplicates here... updated.

Answer (score 2):

The solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338884/sql-server-distinct-union-for-one-column) should be adaptable to those environments, as it's standard SQL (you can use `ISNULL` if `COALESCE` is not available).  I'm not sure what the availability of `FULL OUTER JOIN` is, but it should be available on all three platforms as well.

In your case, the solution will end up looking like:

```
SELECT  p1.cod,  ISNULL(p1.des, p2.des) AS des
FROM parameters1 p1
    FULL OUTER JOIN parameters2 p2 ON p1.cod = p2.cod
```

...but... MySQL apparently doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`, so you can use another trick in that case:

```
SELECT  p1.cod,  ISNULL(p1.des, p2.des) AS des
FROM parameters1 p1
    LEFT JOIN parameters2 p2 ON p1.cod = p2.cod
UNION ALL
SELECT  p2.cod, p2.des
FROM parameters2 p2
    LEFT JOIN parameters1 p1 ON p1.cod = p2.cod
WHERE p1.cod IS NULL
```

Comment: the solution does not cover cases where a parameter lives only in the second table, that is the result will always be the same as a simple select from the first table

Comment: It doesn't work because if i remove the record from parameters 1 i don't get anything ... See the updated question, and sorry for not being much accurate in the question.

Comment: Shoot.  Do you have both `LEFT` and `RIGHT JOIN` support in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Change second union query to get only parameters2 where parameters2.id is not in parameters1.