# SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns along with other columns

Tags: sql, distinct

I want to run query like below

```
select distinct (columnA, columnB, columnC), columnD from MY_TABLE where columnA IS NOT NULL AND columnB IS NOT NULL AND columnC is NOT NULL;
```

I only want distinct of columnA, columnB and columnC and NOT ON columnD.
But SQL developer is pointing an error right after columnA, 
How can I fix this?

I tried to fix my query using GROUP BY

```
select columnA, columnB, columnC, (select count(*) from TABLE2 WHERE table2columnA = myTable.columnA) from MY_TABLE myTable where columnA IS NOT NULL AND columnB IS NOT NULL AND columnC is NOT NULL GROUP BY columnA, columnB, columnC;
```

Notice that my columnD is actually another select statement?
But this is giving me error

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

This is not a duplicate of that another question

Comment: Thank you Vikrant. I cannot mark has duplicate yet ^.^

Comment: No. It's not duplicate of that question. I am trying to get distinct of columns (A, B & C) and a non-distinct column D.

Comment: Suppose you have the tuples (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 5) and (0, 2, 3, 4). What would you expect from your query?

Comment: I suggest you to use `OUTER APPLY` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64728511/4344976).

Comment: The problem here is DBMS doesn't know what result to show for the other columns (because there can be multiple candidates). For example, this might fix the issue because it output the first candidate
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1)
       col2, col3
FROM   tableA
ORDER  BY col1, col2, col3;
Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group) questions second answer